# Scraping wikipedia table r

Tags: html, r, screen-scraping, rvest

Trying to scrape the first 8 tables (very high, high, medium, low) from the human development index in Wikipedia.

Started with but getting a list of zero. What am I doing wrong? New to R :(

```
libray(rvest)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index#Complete_list_of_countries"
webpage <- read_html(url)

hdi_tables <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')

head(hdi_tables, n = 10)

scrape <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table') %>%
  html_table()

head(scrape, n=10)
```

Comment: Might be easier to get the original data [from the source](http://hdr.undp.org/en/data). You can select `HDI` and download a CSV file for years to 2015. The tables at Wikipedia are 2016 estimates.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to work with the [original data source](http://hdr.undp.org/en/data):

Select "Human Development Index (HDI)" in both the drop-down select lists, then click the "Download Data" link to get a CSV file named `Human Development Index (HDI).csv`.

Read it into R:

```
library(tidyverse)
Human_Development_Index_HDI_ <- read_csv("path/to/Human Development Index (HDI).csv", 
                                         skip = 1)
```

You can reshape the data, get the values for 2015 and classify countries as low, medium, high or very high:

```
hdi <- Human_Development_Index_HDI_ %>% 
  gather(Year, HDI, -`HDI Rank (2015)`, -Country) %>% 
  filter(Year == "2015") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(Year), 
         classification = cut(HDI,
                              breaks = c(0, 0.549, 0.699, 0.799, 1), 
                              labels = c("low", "medium", "high", "very_high")))

hdi

# A tibble: 188 x 5
   `HDI Rank (2015)`             Country  Year   HDI classification
               <int>               <chr> <dbl> <dbl>         <fctr>
 1               169         Afghanistan  2015 0.479            low
 2                75             Albania  2015 0.764           high
 3                83             Algeria  2015 0.745           high
 4                32             Andorra  2015 0.858      very_high
 5               150              Angola  2015 0.533            low
 6                62 Antigua and Barbuda  2015 0.786           high
 7                45           Argentina  2015 0.827      very_high
 8                84             Armenia  2015 0.743           high
 9                 2           Australia  2015 0.939      very_high
10                24             Austria  2015 0.893      very_high
# ... with 178 more rows
```

You could change the filter to get values for 2014 too, if you want to replicate the "change from previous year" values in the Wikipedia table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with parsing the wikipedia markup language instead, you could try using [WikipediR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WikipediR/WikipediR.pdf) to grab the markup of the page (from skimming the documentation, try page_content with `as_wikitext` set to true). Then you'll get some lines that all look like this:

```
|  1 || {{steady}} ||style="text-align:left"| {{flag|Norway}} || 0.949 || {{increase}} 0.001
```

This should be parseable in R using `strsplit` or something.